# Get values from Child Component sent to Parent model Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a simple form, and as part of that form i want to implement user selection using material table selection rather than select field so I can see details of the user before selecting them.

I got the form and selectmodel working however i don't know how to get the selectionmodel data back to the parent model and bind it to a form control. So hoping for some help

Example code:

**allocation.component.HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="newAllocationForm">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper formArrayName="formArray" linear #stepper>
    <mat-step formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray.get([0])">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>New Capability Details</ng-template>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Vehicle ID" formControlName="vehicleId" required>
            <mat-error>
              Vehicle Id is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step formGroupName="1" [stepControl]="formArray.get([1])">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Select Users</ng-template>
      <app-user-table></app-user-table>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
      <p>You are now done.</p>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()"
          [disabled]="newAllocationForm.invalid">Submit</button>

        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

**allocation.component.ts**

```
export class CapabilityNewComponent implements OnInit {
  newAllocationForm= this.fb.group({
    formArray: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        vehicleId: ['', Validators.required],
      }),
      this.fb.group({
        users: ['']
      })
    ])
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get formArray(): FormArray | null { return this.newAllocationForm.get('formArray') as FormArray; }

  onSubmit() {
    // get values from child component table and attach to parent form
  }

}
```

**user-table.component.ts**

```
export class UserTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<UserTableItem>;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['select', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'position'];

  constructor(public userService: UserService) {
    userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
}
```

**user-table.component.html**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
          [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
          [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.FirstName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.LastName}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Position</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Position}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="dataSource?.data.length" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

As you can see this is mostly standard code taken from Angular Material website (nothing fancy).
I've looked into @Output but cannot understand how it would work on this model.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use instances of `UserTableComponent` as a regular form control, you need it to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

I've put together a [Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma618311546433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html). To see the output, don't use Stackblitz embedded dev tools. **Use the browser's native dev tools**.

This interface allows any custom angular component to be part of an angular form.

It's comprised of 4 methods:

1. **writeValue(obj: any):** void
   This method is used by angular to set the value in your component whenever you use `AbstractControl#setValue`.
2. **registerOnChange(fn: any):** void
   The method (`fn`), passed by angular to your component, must be called whenever the overall value of your component has changed. The new value must be passed as an argument.
3. **registerOnTouched(fn: any):** void
   The method `fn`, passed by angular to your component, must be called whenever you consider that your component must notify angular it's been touched.
4. **setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean)?:** void
   This method, optional, will be used by angular whenever the parent component invokes `AbstractControl#enable` and `AbstractControl#disable`

   After doing the above 4 items, you also need to provide your class as a control value accessor provider.

   So:

```js
@Component({
...
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => UserTableComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class UserTableComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  onChange: (any[] | null) => void = 
      (SelectionModel<any> | null) => {};

  onTouched: () =>  void = () => {};

  writeValue(value: SelectionModel<any> | null) {
    // set the values of your component
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (any | null) => void) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    if(isDisabled) {
      // prevent your table to be selected
    } else {
      // enable your table for being selected
    }
  }

  // whenever the selection changes, you should emit it again
  notifyChanges() {
    this.onChange(this.selection);
  }
}
```

In your table component, you would have this:

```html
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
              (change)="_setSelection($event, row)"
              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
</mat-checkbox>
```

and in your typescript:

```js
_setSelection(row: any, change: EventEmitter<MatCheckboxChange>) {
  if(change) {
    selection.toggle(row);
    this.onChange(this.selection.selected);
  }
}
```

after doing that you could do:

```html
<app-user-table formControlName="controlName"></app-user-name>
```

Comment: Interesting, so how does this return the value to the parent component?

Comment: By calling the onChange (the last method in my example)

Comment: I've put together a Stackblitz demo.

Comment: I played with it yesterday, looks good. I also ran across @ViewChild approach which simplifies it further

Answer (score 0):

Use an `EventEmitter`. For example, in your parent component:

**parent.ts**

```
functionThatReceivesDataFromChild($event: YourClass) {
  // do stuff with your $event object here.
}
```

**parent.html**

```
<app-child-component (childOutputProperty)="functionThatReceivesDataFromChild($event)"></app-child-component>
```

And in your child component:

**child.component.ts**

```
import { ..., Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

...

@Output() childOutputProperty: EventEmitter<YourClass> = new EventEmitter()

let myFormGroup: FormGroup = ...

formSubmitPressed() {
   this.childOutputProperty.emit(this.myFormGroup.value)
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">

   <button (click)="formSubmitPressed()">Submit<button>
</form>
```

Relevant documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event